# Making a heatmap with a precomputed distance matrix and data matrix in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have made a heatmap based upon a regular data matrix in R, the package I use is `pheatmap`. Regular clustering of my samples is performed by the `distfun` function within the package.

Now I want to attach a precomputed distance matrix (generated by Unifrac) to my previously generated matrix/heatmap. Is this possible?

Comment: @Lars What do you want to modify: the heatmap or the dendrogram?

Comment: I would like to modify the heatmap in such a way that my columns get clustered according to the pre-computed distance matrix

Comment: @Lars I don't see any way to have different clustering scheme (distance + method) for rows and columns, after a quick look at the code. Some suggestions were provided on this [related question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6890/plotting-a-heatmap-given-a-dendrogram-and-a-distance-matrix-in-r); otherwise, the simplest solution is to play with the code and add your own modifications. I can show you how to do it if you want.

Comment: If you could help me with this I would be thrilled !

Comment: Would it be easier to use the mixOmics package instead ? I have it installed, however the looks are not as nice as in the pheatmap package

Comment: @Lars `pheatmap` relies on `grid` plotting functionalities, which is the reason why it looks so nice.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so you can just look at the code by typing the name of the function at the R prompt, or use `edit(pheatmap)` to see it in your default editor.

Around line 14 and 23, you'll see that another function is called for computing the distance matrices (for rows and columns), given a distance function (R `dist`) and a method (compatible with `hclust` for hierarchical clustering in R). What does this function do? Use `getAnywhere("cluster_mat")` to print it on screen, and you soon notice that it does nothing more than returning an `hclust` object, that is your dendrogram computed from the specified distance and linkage options.

So, if you already have your distance matrix, change line 14 (rows) or 23 (columns) so that it reads, e.g.

```
tree_row = hclust(my.dist.mat, method="complete")
```

where `my.dist.mat` is your own distance function, and `complete` is one of the many methods available in `hclust` (see `help(hclust)`). Here, it is important to use `fix(pheatmap)` and not `edit(pheatmap)`; otherwise, the edited function will not be callable in the correct environment/namespace.

This is a quick and dirty hack that I would not recommend with larger package. It seems to work for me at least, that is I can use a custom distance matrix with complete linkage for the rows.

In sum, assuming your distance matrix is stored in a variable named `dd`,

```
library(pheatmap)
fix(pheatmap)
# 1. change the function as you see fit
# 2. save and go back to R
# 3. if your custom distance matrix was simply read as a matrix, make sure
#    it is read as a distance matrix
my.dist.map <- dd  # or as.dist(dd)
```

Then, you can call `pheatmap` as you did but now it will use the results of `hclust` applied to `my.dist.map` with `complete` linkage. Please note that you just have to ensure that `cluster_rows=TRUE` (which is the default). Now, you may be able to change

- the linkage method
- choose between rows or columns

by editing the package function appropriately.

Comment: I will try this at once and let you know how it went. Thanks for your huge effort- greatly appreciate it .

Comment: +1 awesome answer and great reference for how to bend source code to suit your needs. This type of thing comes up on SO all the time, I wish there was a way to have this available in the R-tag on SO as a FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

As of version 1.0.10, the input parameter `clustering_distance_rows` and `clustering_distance_cols` can take a `dist` object to impose the precomputed distance for clustering.