# How to extract residuals from function cv.lm in R?

Tags: r, cross-validation

How can I call residuals out from function `cv.lm`?

`cv.lm$ss` gives me the cross validation sum of squares, but I need individual residuals from each fold.

Is it possible to call out?

Comment: What is cv.lm? If it's a function, which package is it from?

Comment: cv.lm() is a function in the DAAG package for R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the R code, computation for individual fold are done in the inner loop, starting with

```
for (i in sort(unique(rand))) { # line 37
```

but results are just returned with a `print` statement (line 67-68), if `printit=TRUE` (which is the default). So, you can use what I suggested for a [related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10347/making-a-heatmap-with-a-precomputed-distance-matrix-and-data-matrix-in-r/10349#10349) and edit the function in place so that it returns the SS for each fold in a list. That is, use

```
fix(cv.lm)
```

at the R prompt, then add the following three lines in the code

```
...
sumss <- 0
sumdf <- 0
ssl <- list()            # (*)
...
    ms <- ss/num
    ssl[[i]] <- ss       # (*)
    if (printit)
        cat("\nSum of squares =", round(ss, 2), "   Mean square =",
...
invisible(c(ss = sumss, df = sumdf, 
          ss.fold=ssl))  # (*)
}
```

To check that it worked, try

```
> res <- cv.lm(printit=FALSE, plotit=FALSE)
> str(res)
List of 5
  ss      : num 59008
  df      : num 15
  ss.fold1: num 24351
  ss.fold2: num 20416
  ss.fold3: num 14241
```

You can also returned a list of the fold SS by replacing `ss.fold=ssl` with `ss.fold=list(ssl)`, so that the output would look like

```
List of 3
  ss     : num 59008
  df     : num 15
  ss.fold:List of 3
  ..$ : num 24351
  ..$ : num 20416
  ..$ : num 14241
```

Comment: I'm in doubt about same point. But i think that this package was updated and i didnt find where should i add this 3 lines. Could you help me?

Comment: @Arthur Indeed, it has been updated! (The contrary would have been surprising.) Not a big deal, though: you can follow the above steps by noting that the inner loop now starts around line 97 (depending on your version of `DAAG`; mine is 1.15, packaged on 2012-07-26 10:02:12 UTC).